# Is it possible to use generated Java interface instead of AIDL

Tags: java, android, android-service, in-app-billing, aidl

I need to use the In App Billing service in my app. I'm wondering if i can put the generated .java in a package and reference it instead of using IInAppBillingService.aidl.

In theory, couldn't it make the same communication with the service?

Comment: Any particular reason why you'd want to make more work for yourself with the same result?

Comment: There is more to the code generated by AIDL than a Java interface, as you can tell by examining that generated code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I will compile the project that includes AIDL referencing classes as a jar. 
I need to set the pom's _packaging_ parameter to _apk_ for Maven to generate classes properly from AIDL. It compiles the project into an apk as well as a jar when i do it. Just seemed unnecessary when i could use the class directly and set _packaging_ to _jar_. It's not a hindrance or prevention but I'm wondering if that's possible.. I thought answers could help me understand more about AIDL/IDL concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use Java generated files instead of AIDL. Basically, AIDL interface is translated into java files during the compilation of your program and then is not used anymore. This pattern is used sometimes in Android platform programming (for instance, ActivityManager is not created from AIDL interface but there are separate java files that implement proxy and stub interfaces). I think that you can just take a generated java file from AIDL and put it directly in your service and client projects.